# Firebase Admob in Flutter: Disposing Ads even if they're loading

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-admob

I'm using the plugin: firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+4
And I want to load ads only on a specific page in a PageView. When the user moves to another page I want the ads to be disposed. However, I've encountered a problem where the ad only gets disposed if its already loaded and shown. Otherwise it loads and displays on the new tab.

How can I prevent an ad from loading if it hasn't loaded already?

Here's the code:

```
MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
  contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
  birthday: DateTime.now(),
  childDirected: false,
  designedForFamilies: false,
  gender: MobileAdGender.male, 
  testDevices: <String>[], 
);

BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("BannerAd event is $event");
  },
);
myBanner
  ..load()
  ..show(
    anchorOffset: 60.0,
    horizontalCenterOffset: 10.0,
    anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
  );
```

And in the dispose method of the page I call the following function:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    disposeAds();
    super.dispose();
}

void disposeAds()async{
    _banner?.dispose();
    _banner=null;
}
```

What I want to know is how to prevent an ad from loading after the page is disposed? On iOS it automatically seems to do this but not on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [admob_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter)

This package transform your Admob banner in a widget

```
AdmobBanner(
      adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
      adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
    ));
```

then, you can use like any other widget

```
 Container getBanner() {
    return new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: AdmobBanner(
          adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
          adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to use the official package. Does this have the Mobile Ad Targeting info?

Comment: No. I opened the code of the package and is basically an AndroidView, maybe you can build your own AndroidView with the Mobile Ad Targeting info.